# When does reflect type.Size() return 0?

Tags: go, reflection

I have some generic code that uses reflection to handle struct fields. These fields may or may not include C types, referenced through Cgo.

One problem I encountered was that those aforementioned C types may be "incomplete structs", for instance:
`typedef struct unknown u;`. This can result in a panic later on in the code.

To avoid situations like this, I want to skip these fields. I found that doing a check on the `reflect.Type` where `Size()` returns `0` correctly tells me this:

```golang
if myType.Size() == 0 {
    return
}
```

But I was wondering. are there any other instances where a `reflect.Type` will return a size of `0`? In other words, is it possible any other types be skipped?

Answer (score 5):

A struct with no members has a size of zero.

```
reflect.TypeOf(struct{}{}).Size() == 0
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/l5j4JoGyisM).

Comment: I think this is the only scenario we can make a type with size 0, but in @robbieperry22's code, before checking `myType.Size()`, nil check should be done. otherwise it can be panic.